# home web/file server

Tags: hosting, media

At Home we have a lot of media Content on three computers. I was thinking of centralizing them on one single machine that runs a web server that hosts all the content, and when we fetch a URL like : http://localhost/music it will show a HTML file that lists all the music files on the computer, and when we click  on a file,  it gets downloaded.

I don't  know  what to use so as to make this thing, I think Apache as a server  and PHP as a language..., any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you need PHP? Apache or nginx or any other reasonable web server will generate file listings for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install FreeNAS on your machine

http://www.freenas.org/

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to go that far.  Just install apache on a computer and have your music folder be a web directory.  You should be able to navigate to the page like so:  http://whateverip/music/ and apache will serve up that html page like you are suggesting.

Comment: So I just need to create  a script  that lists all the music content and put it on the http://localhost/music  dir  .??

Comment: You don't even need a script.  If you put your music folder in the root of your apache web path, apache will automatically serve up the content.

Answer (score 0):

If using windows, XAMPP is a pretty good solution.  You don't really need the PHP part, because all you need on the server after installing a WAMP solution, is to place all your content in the folder that the server uses.

If using Linux, definately install LAMP, there is an easy install of it whether using Ubuntu or other Linux distrubtions.

If using a MAC, there are similar solutions as LAMP.  Some are hassle-free.

In any case, all of these use Apache as the server; that is the way to go.  It's not as hard as you think, just install the software, and put your files in the appropriate directory, then from each of the other machines, to find the files you would probably type this into your address bar:

```
http://192.168.1.101/
```

Which of course is the address of the web server on your Local area network.  It is very likely an address that is very similar to that, maybe ending with two different last two numbers.

Comment: Thank  you ' but I think that this freeNas  is what I need :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would second the freenas route if what you want to store is valuable to you in terms of time or money or electricity. It makes a great headless fileserver with web GUI, supports ZFS filesystem (similar to  software RAID5 so you can lose a disk and not lose your data). More valuable to me it also supports replication to a duplicate server.

It can run on very low power hardware using freeBSD as the OS. I measured one of my boxes and it uses about 45 Watts. The OS loads from a USB stick so all your disks become data disks. It holds the system in RAM so your USB does not get any writes to it so the USB lasts a very long time. It will serve CIFS for your windows boxes, AFP for your macs, and NFS for your linux systems. Plug-ins allow for such things as DLNA media servers. I have had three boxes running stable with no reboots for over a year with 6x 3TB drives per box.

A typical hardware setup might be ASUS C60M1-I AMD Fusion board (combined CPU/VGA/NICC/6SATA)for about 75 bucks, 16GB RAM, PSU, USB stick - and voila - add 3 hard drives and you have a low-power RAID fileserver. Get two and you can replicate one server to another in a different physical location.